# Rails not rendering before execute next command

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, exec, thin, webrick

I'm using Rails 4 and I want to execute a Python script after edit a controller.

I've done:

```
 if @a_serverconfiguration.update(a_serverconfiguration_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @a_serverconfiguration, notice: 'Device configuration was successfully updated. Next time, you have to access to new ip configuration. Rebooting device, this would take a while...' }
   format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @a_serverconfiguration }
Thread.new do      
    exec "sudo python /home/pi/Desktop/starting.py"
end
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @a_serverconfiguration.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

But I can't see my show page before execute python script. This script reboot after 10 seconds, so when user updates controller, Can't see the message 'Device configuration was successfully updated. Next time, you have to access to new ip configuration. Rebooting device, this would take a while...'. Webrick waits for 10 seconds and go down.

I've tried with Webrick and thin and both do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well : you want your controller render a response before you python script is finished.

Use threads permit to run multiple code block a the same time, I think you want to execute you python script like a background job.

Instead to use Thread have a look to [delayed_job gem][1]. This gem encapsulates and execute longer tasks in the background.